# Does a second meaning of "Hypotenuse" exist?

Tags: pronunciation, jokes

I've recently saw [this comic strip](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506153157/https://www.thecomicstrips.com/store/add.php?iid=70401):

[image]
<sub>(source: [cartoonistgroup.com](https://www.cartoonistgroup.com/properties/fande/art_images/cg4e9300b4e9cd8.jpg))</sub>

> You may be right, Pythagoras, but everyone’s going to laugh if you call it a “hypotenuse”.

Does "hypotenuse" have a second meaning? What's funny about the word? Is it something about a wrong pronunciation?

Comment: I suspect it's just that the writer thought the word sounded funny. I don't know of any other meaning in English. My dictionary says the Greek means "to stretch under", which doesn't sound particularly funny either.

Comment: @Jay: I suspect if you asked a large number of native speakers to identify the "funniest" word out of [motorcycle, entertainment, superstitious, constellation, hypotenuse, opposition, predatory, mandatory, etc.](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080901073709AAiwqIS), forced to make a choice, the vast majority would pick [hypotenuse](http://chasingthehypotenuse.wordpress.com/). Those are useful links, btw.

Comment: "I’m very well acquainted, too, with matters mathematical,
I understand equations, both the simple and quadratical,
About binomial theorem I’m teeming with a lot o’ news –
With many cheerful facts about the square of the hypotenuse." - W. S. Gilbert, Pirates of Penzance. In the version of the play that I saw, after singing "lot o' news" the actor paused and said, "Hmm, what rhymes with lot o' news ... oh ..."

Comment: It all has to do with the old joke about the squaw on the hippopotamus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd have to see the context on the joke, but when I was a teenager in math class we'd laugh about it being "High Pot in Use".

Comment: Context: "Frank and Ernest" Oct 15, 2006 and May 13, 1984... http://www.frankandernest.com

Comment: That was doubtless a peculiarity of your math class or some other highly regional interpretation. I don't think there's any reason to postulate alliterative words to make *hypotenuse* "funny".